# How can I run logstash manually?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I am trying to run logstash 5.4 manually but any commands that I have found seems to work. I need to run it manually since it doesn't start up.

I have followed the documentation which says

```
$sudo opt/logstash --path.settings=/etc/logstash/logstash.yml -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
sudo: opt/logstash: command not found

$sudo /bin/logstash --path.settings=/etc/logstash/logstash.yml -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
sudo: /bin/logstash: command not found
```

I have tried as well `sudo service logstash start` and nothing and I don't get any log even having configured it

```
/etc/logstash# cat logstash.yml
# ------------ Debugging Settings --------------
#
# Options for log.level:
#   * fatal
#   * error
#   * warn
#   * info (default)
#   * debug
#   * trace
#
log.level: debug
path.logs: /var/log/logstash
```

How can I run it manually?

Answer (score 1):

The default install location of Logstash is `/usr/share/logstash`. Try this:

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --path.settings=/etc/logstash/logstash.yml -e "input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }"
```

If that doesn't work, you can try to gain insight on where Logstash is by using the `whereis` command. For example on my machine I get...

```
root@fylie:~# whereis logstash
logstash: /etc/logstash /usr/share/logstash
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a program in the current directory you can use like.

> for example : ./logstash --version

Over and out.